# Nonunital C*-Algebra: Proper Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra without unit.

Does there exist a nontrivial proper ideal
that does not lie in a maximally nontrivial proper ideal?

(For the unital case this follows easily by Zorn's lemma.)

Whatwould be an example of such?

Comment: Why doesn't Zorn's lemma apply here in the same way?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Because a it may fail to be an inductive order. Crucial is the existence of a common element outside of every proper ideal, namely the identity.

Comment: Aha... interesting problem

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks! :) I thought it would be nice to know what and how about it may go wrong in the non-unital case..

Comment: See this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172215

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan That's it I am looking for - thank you!!!