# Showing $x \in R$ is invertible if and only if $x$ is not contained in any maximal Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Here $R$ is commutative.

$\Rightarrow$ is fairly easy to prove as every Ideal containing a unit must be the entire Ring so it cannot be maximal. But I'm having some trouble with $\Leftarrow$, this is what I got so far:

We want to get a contradiction, so assume $x$ is not a unit so $xR$ is a proper Ideal, let $A$ be the set of proper Ideals containing $x$, $A$ is not empty and partially ordered by Inclusion. I want to use Zorn's lemma here but I cant figure out what the supremum of a chain in $A$ is, I know that the union of the Ideals in the chain is an Ideal containing $x$ but I cant figure out why it must be a proper Ideal i.e. not $R$.

Comment: This standard proof is discussed here *many* times, e.g. see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2202500/242) in the dupe for full details. Note $(x)$ is a proper ideal when $x$ is a nonunit, so it is a special case of the dupe. Note also that [this fails for rings without identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/154547/242). Please search for answers before posing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the a chain of proper ideals containing $x$, and let $U=\bigcup\mathscr{C}$. If $1_R\in U$, then there is some $I\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $1_R\in I$, which is impossible.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.